# How to set a proxy on chrome's remote debugging port in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, google-chrome-devtools

I'm running a chrome instance using cmd as follows :

`chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=8798 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\HP Elitebook\Desktop\Projects\Project Gmail\chromedriver-win64\localhost"`

I now want to set a proxy for this chrome instance in selenium. I'm using the following code to check and scrape my ip but it seems that I'm missing something and shows me my actual ip address.

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver


PROXY = "35.236.207.242:33333"

os.environ['PATH'] += os.getcwd()+r"\chromedriver-win64"

options = Options()  
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress','127.0.0.1:8798')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome( options=options)

chrome.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com")

myip =  WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ipv4"]')))

print(myip.text)
```

Please note that I've tested it and it's working fine in the default chrome browser that pops up when I remove

```
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress','127.0.0.1:8798')
```

[image: Expected Output but in the chrome remote debugger]

Comment: it's showing the same IP you set the proxy to... (or am I missing something?)  it's better to just to use a proxy that's set machine-wide.  You're also setting a debug port which assumes Chrome is already launched, so that launch flag for proxy will probably not be applied unless you launch it that way initially.

Comment: No, the screenshot is what I'm getting with the default chrome launch through the selenium webdriver. The main idea was to get it working with setting a debug port because I want rotating ips for my project and a system wide approach might not be the best one.